# ¿Como puedo hacer un ciclo for en php igual que javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código javascript (escribe 2 veces con valores diferentes):

```
 <p id="cantidad"></p>

 <script>
 var viene_de_array = ["0", "1", "2"];
 var productos = "";
 var a;
 for (a = 1; a < 3; a++) {
 productos += viene_de_array[a]+"<br>";
 } 
 document.getElementById("cantidad").innerHTML = productos;
 </script>
```

Y este es el código PHP (escribe una vez, solo el ultimo valor):

```
 $productos = ""; 
 for($a=1; $a<3; $a++){
 $productos += $viene_de_array[$a]; 
 }
 echo "<p>" . $productos . "</p> //Y aquí solo escribe la ultima "fila"(una)
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que me funcione igual en PHP? que se haga la repetición dentro del ciclo, pero afuera se haga el "echo" (fuera de{}). Si lo pongo dentro del ciclo funciona perfectamente, pero necesito me funcione como en javascript.

Comment: Dónde está la declaración de `totalproductos` y que debe almacenar un array?

Comment: @BetaM Vienen de una "constante `(const totalproductos = { };)`" y traen un numero, el 1 y 2. En javascript escribe bien el 1 y el 2 y en php solo me escribe el numero 2

Comment: ¿podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando la declaración completa de `$totalproductos` en PHP?

Comment: @Pollo ¡Listo! para que se entienda mejor viene de un arreglo, ahorita pongo el arreglo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay 2 temas, el primero que puede ser un error o no:

1. Los arrays empiezan en el índice 0, quizás sea intencional que quieras mostrar el 2do y 3er item, pero por las dudas tené en cuenta que para ver los primeros 2 elementos sería:

   ```
   for ($a=0; $a<2; $a++) {
   ```
2. En PHP se concatena con un [**punto** `.`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)  (*el `+` es para sumar números*).

   Por ejemplo: `$a = $b . $c;`

   ```
   $a .= $variable;
   ```

Comment: También en JavaScript empiezan en el índice 0

Comment: @BetaM sí, gracias... no era intención diferenciar de JavaScript sino de otros lenguajes... es cierto que quedaba poco claro

Comment: @Pollo ¡Muchísimas Gracias!

Comment: @BetaM De cualquier forma agregare el arreglo para que se identifique (Si entran otras personas con el mismo problema) ¡Gracias de cualquier forma!

Comment: @Pollo espero no molestar con la edición hecha, solo fue para agregarle al OP el enlace de la doc para que cheque mas sobre la concatenación

Comment: @BetaM no hace falta ni que aclares hombre!!!! Podemos discutir infinitamente sobre métodos y código al responder, pero estamos los 2 remando para el mismo lado!!! Además, no sé vos, yo me divierto así :-)

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

for ($contador = 0; $contador<2; $contador++) {
    echo "<p>{$contador}</p>";
}
```

Es decir:

- Si vas a manejar un array con valores ya definidos (*como muestras en el JS*), entonces el for no es el adecuado y debería tener una sintaxis medida por el conteo de elementos que existen dentro de el (*para darle mas utilidad*), mas o menos así:

  ```
  for ($contador=0; $a<count($viene_de_array); $a++){
  ```
- Por otro lado la existencia de esta variable `$productos` no hace mucho sentido, pues si planeamos ocupar esos valores entonces ¿por qué no tomarlos directo del array declarado? así como el hecho de que parece tratas de igualarla con el array previamente declarado
- En cuyo caso entonces dejamos que los límites de inicio y fin del ciclo queden únicamente como las *vueltas* que dará para estar imprimiendo un contenido específico y el contenido de cada párrafo se generará como en el punto anterior

  ```
  $valoresVector = [111, 222];
  for ($contador=0; $contador<count($valoresVector); $contador++){
      echo "<p>{$valoresVector[$contador]}</p>";
  }
  ```

Pero honestamente es demasiado considerando la primer opción propuesta, sin contar el hecho de que puedes dejarle al for que genere tantas etiquetas como iteraciones haga aprovechando su naturaleza ciclica.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!